# Obfuscate/minify code in place for npm package publish

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, obfuscation, minify

I have dist directory that looks like this 
[image: dist directory]

Requirements: The root and each folder has `.js` and `.d.ts` for typing. I want to ship this to npm after obfuscating/minifying (to avoid reverse engineering). I need this to happen **in place** (all the folder structure intact), and also **preserve** the `.d.ts`. I use this package internally to develop and 1. need the flexibility to look into each folder directory, and 2. use the defined types.

What I've tried: I've tried webpack but since webpack minifies the whole codebase to one file, and does not preserve the typings file, I don't think it's the right choice.

Question: Is there a way to achieve this? Ideally the directory itself would almost be unchanged, just the contents would be minified. Thanks!

Comment: Obfuscation is pretty ineffective for preventing reverse engineering, and the point of minification should _only_ be to reduce bandwidth when serving the script file. If someone wants to reverse engineer your JavaScript, they'll be able to regardless of how you've transformed it, if it's publicly available. With that being said, [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) has some good plugins for transpiling, bundling and minifying TypeScript, and [`rollup-plugin-dts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-dts) in particular allows you to generate `.d.ts` files as well.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts In order to avoid reverse engineering, what do you suggest? Webpack seems to be the right choice, but I need to be able to reach `require(./command)` to enable to bin command. Also, thanks for that recommendation will check it out.

Comment: If you want to avoid reverse engineering, the only thing you can do is to provide a web service with an API that conceals the implementation server-side. Client-side JavaScript is simply _not capable_ of hardening against reverse engineering.

Comment: By the way, if you want an example of how configuration looks with rollup, you can check out [one of my recent projects](https://github.com/patrickroberts/typed-scheduler) that uses it for generating `dst` files for `npm` very similar to what you seem to be looking for.